# Nextjs - Useeffect not update table after db change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

My problem is when i add useEffect(() => {.........}, [getData]); It update table but several time.(infinite loop). This will crush app. How can i update table when db updated? I already checked other question in here but couldn't find solution. I faced this problem 4-5 times. I need to learn correct solution. Thank you.

```
const [getData, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new Api();
    let mounted = true;
    if (!localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
    if (mounted && localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      api
        .getRequest(`${process.env.NEXT_API_URL}api/clients`)
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
          dispatch(setUserData({ ...data }));
          setData(data);
        });
    }
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

 return (
 getData &&
 getData 
  .filter((current) => current.id === selectId.id).slice(0, 5)
  .map((record, index) => (
   <Accordion key={index} className="border-bottom">
     <Accordion.Toggle as="div" eventKey={record.id}>
       <Row className="py-2">
         <Col md={2} className="mobile-hide">
           {strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", new Date(record.created_at))}
         </Col>
         <Col md={1} className="text-uppercase">
                                    {record.name}
         </Col>
         <Col md={2}>{record.amount - record.fee}</Col>
         <Col md={2} className="text-uppercase">
                                    {record.state}
         </Col>
         <Col md={5} className="mobile-hide">
         <div className="text-right transaction-link">
           <Link href={record.txid !== null ? record.tx_url : ""}>
             <a target="_blank">{record.txid !== null ? (record.txid).substr(0, 13) + "...." + (record.txid).substr(-13) : ""}</a>
           </Link>
         </div>
       </Col>
     </Row>
                                
   </Accordion.Toggle>
  </Accordion>
  )
 )
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed problem temporarily with following code:

```
const [getData, setData] = useState([]);
const value = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new Api();
    let mounted = true;
    if (!localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
    const id = setInterval(() => {
    if (mounted && localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      api
        .getRequest(`${process.env.NEXT_API_URL}api/clients`)
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
          dispatch(setUserData({ ...data }));
          setData(data);
        });
    }
    }, 5000)
    return () => {mounted = false, clearInterval(id)};
  }, []);
```

So, every 5 second useEffect fetch Api. I don't like this but it is okey for now.

Comment: The infinite loop happens because with `setData` you modify `getData`; this will re-fire again the `useEffect` that calls `setData` again.... but in your case you don't need `[getData]` in `useEffect` deps list.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito But when new data added to DB. useEffect not update table.

Comment: In your case no because `useEffect` as is will be called one time at component's loading. But I don't see the code in which you update db. Could you show us?

Comment: @rubiest If you want the UI to update when your database is updated in real-time (without reloading the page) you'll need to poll the API for changes. The UI has no way of knowing that your database has changed otherwise.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Yes i didn't share full code it is too big. I will implement websocket for this.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, after search on internet you are right. Need to compare old db and new db. Best thing to add websocket. Thank you.

Comment: @rubiest yes, websocket is the best choice. Have a nice coding =)